# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open. error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a set of code inside `try..catch` block which is giving me error as

> The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open

```
try
    {
        MainEnqMkey = InsertUpdateDelete.InsertUpdateDeleteCls.InsertUpdateDelete_oracle(HidMode.Value, Convert.ToInt32(HidMKey.Value), "XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMNT_MST", "MKEY", "AM", sb.ToString());

        if (Request.QueryString["Mode"] != "M")
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            OracleCommand ObjPriCmd_seq2 = new OracleCommand("select XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMNT_MST_SEQ.nextval from dual", ObjPriCon); // generating ref no here.
            string strRefNo = Convert.ToString(ObjPriCmd_seq2.ExecuteOracleScalar());

            Response.Write("<script language=javascript> alert('Your Document No is : " + strRefNo.ToString() + "')</script>");

            OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand("Update XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMNT_MST set DOC_NO = '" + strRefNo.ToString() + "' where MKEY = '" + MainEnqMkey + "'", ObjPriCon); // Updating ref no here

            OracleCommand cmd3 = new OracleCommand("Update xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst set LAST_DOC_NO = '" + txtdocno.Value + "' where project_id = '" + ddlProject.SelectedValue + "' and VILLAGE = '" + ddlVillage.SelectedValue + "' and SURVEY_AREA_7_12 = '" + ddl712.SelectedValue + "' and LEGAL_ENTITY = '" + txtCompName.Value + "' " + 
                                                    " and TALUKA = '" + ddlTaluka.SelectedValue + "'");  // updating doc as last doc no

            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            ObjPriCon.Close();
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record Saved Successfully');window.location ='Frm_Agreement_Master.aspx?TranType=AM&PView=N&Mode=A&Redirect=oracle&Key=0&Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Message.ToString();
    }
```

After

`ObjPriCon.Open();` it goes to catch block and throws the mentioned error.

Comment: You can't open a connection if it's already open - you'll rip it off its hinges!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of opening a open connection, you can check it's state like

```
if (ObjPriCon.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    ObjPriCon.Open();
}
```

Comment: but now getting error as `Invalid operation. The connection is closed.` at line `cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: that's a different issue, you forgot to add the connection `ObjPriCon` as parameter to `cmd3`

Comment: yes, thanks. now it worked after adding the connection

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this with *hacky way*s using connection state, but it is not a good thing to share one connection. Connection pool is your friend. So you can re write your code:

```
using(OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("connectionString"))
{
     conn.Open();
     //your code
     //using block will automatically close your connection when you are done.
}
```

Also currently you are open to **Sql Injection**. Use paramatrized queries

```
OracleCommand cmd2 = new OracleCommand("Update XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMNT_MST set DOC_NO = @Doc_No  where MKEY =@MKey , conn);

cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Doc_No", strRefNo.ToString());
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mkey", MainEnqMkey);

cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Be aware the OracleCommand doesn't support named parameters, so you should define them in same sequence as in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to have ObjPriCon.Close(); in a finally block. If it ever goes into catch then it could not have got closed.

Answer (score 0):

Better you write finally block and within it `ObjPriCon.close()`

```
try   
{   
   ObjPriCon.Open();   

}    
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex; 
}
finally
{
  ObjPriCon.close();
}
```

Comment: There is no need for closing the connection in try if you have it in finally. Finally block is always executed.